# The same graphs with different sizes

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm building big pan-genome graphs in Java Embedded mode. Considering a fixed topology, when I build it in one round the size of database is a bit less than when I build a sub-graph of it and add the rest of graph to it later in another execution of the application. What would be the possible reasons?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather vague. I guess the store files itself will have the same size (`data/graph.db/*store.db`). The difference in size might be caused by the transaction log files (`data/graph.db/*transaction.db*`).

Comment: Thank you. Now I delete all transaction log files after execution. There is still some differences caused by neostore.counts.db* and messages.log files. What are these file, and could I remove them from the database?